# Closure notices appear wrong on Area 51 Discussions

Tags: bug, design, area-51, closed-questions

There is a formatting problem on the closure notices on closed questions on Area 51 Discussions. On most sites, it's supposed to be justified to fill in the entire area. However, on Area 51 Discussions, it stops short of that:

[image: Box terminates 3 cm before the right side]

It used to fill the entire width before. What happened now?

Comment: Area 51 can't be touched, so even if it used to be different, I'm afraid it won't be fixed. Code is too old/fragile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Area 51 can't, but Area 51 *Discussions* can. It does not run on a special code base.

Comment: @AdamLear Is this being looked into right now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is no longer an issue now that the new responsive design has rolled out on Area 51 Discussions.